# check whether all lateinit members of a class have been initialized

Tags: kotlin, jvm, kotlin-lateinit

I would like to create an extension method that helps me validate that all `lateinit` properties of a class have been initialized at a given point in time.
I have come up with the following so far:

```
fun Any.assertLateInitPropertiesAreInitialized() {
    for (member in this::class.memberProperties) {
        if (member.isLateinit) {
            try {
                member.call(this)
            }
            catch (e: Throwable) {
                if (e.cause is UninitializedPropertyAccessException) {
                    throw e
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but it's rather ugly because I have to call the property explicitly which may be quite expensive.

Is there a way to use `isInitialized` instead? I can't figure out how to *bind* my `KProperty1` to `this` so as to get a `KProperty0` so I access it (if it is at all possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `lateinit` properties cannot be nullable, it should be enough to check whether the Java field is `null`. Something like:

```
member.javaField!!.get(this) != null
```